# View uninstall rate in Google Play store

Tags: android, download, uninstallation, rating, google-play

The uninstall rate (#uninstalls / #downloads) is a measure of app performance, according to the new [Developer Distribution Agreement](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html)

> Google may use or publish performance measurements such as uninstall and/or refund rates to identify or remove Products [..]

One could copy the #downloads and #uninstalls from the developer console into an Excel table and the compute the uninstall rate. But that's a tedious task if statistics for several applications need to be checked for each country each day.

Is it possible to view the uninstall rate in the developer console or fetch it programmatically?

Comment: Why is it a good measure of how users like an app? Maybe they really like it but they uninstall because they need space for something else, or maybe they are selling their phone. Maybe if you had a time element in the equation you could argue they don't like it if they uninstall not long after downloading..

Comment: Wow...tedious task! You are really developer!

Answer (score 1):

On the Google Play Developer Console you can see the current number of installs and the total number of installs, for a given application. You can calculate the number of uninstalls by subtracting the current installs from the total installs.

Comment: uninstall_rate = (number of daily uninstalls) / (number of daily installs).